# operator ++ (prefix) with threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, operators

Betting between friends.
sum variable is defined as global.
and we have 2 threads that run over loop 1..100 and increments sum by 1 every loop.

what will be printed?
"sum="?

```
int sum = 0;

void func(){
    for (int i=0 ; i<= 100; i++){
        sum++;
    }
}

int main(){

  t1 = Thread(func);
  t2 = Thread(func);

  t1.start();
  t2.start();

  t1.join();
  t2.join();

  cout << "sum = " << sum;

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Anything could happen. It is UB - http:://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325524/does-integer-overflow-cause-undefined-behavior-because-of-memory-corruption/37325854#37325854

Comment: Out of curiosity, I corrected the program for c++11 and I had "202" as first result, This means that anyone thinking the range is 100-200 is wrong.  For a possible reason, look closely to the code ;)  It remains UB though.

Comment: Note that the title refers to **prefix** operator++, but the code uses **postfix**. Not that that affects the result...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no single value for sum. If there are 0 race conditions, the value will be 200. If there are race conditions on every iteration of the loop (unlikely) it could be as low as 100. Or it could be anywhere in between.

You probably think of sum++ as an atomic operation, but it is actually syntactic sugar for sum = sum + 1. There is the possibility of a race condition within this operation, so sum could be different every time you run it.

Imagine the current value of sum is 10. Then t1 gets into the loop and reads the value of sum (10), and then is stopped to let t2 begin running. t2 will then reads the same value (10) of sum as t1. Then when each thread increments they will both increment it to 11. If there are no other race conditions the end value of sum would be 199.

Here's an even worse case. Imagine the current value of sum is 10 again. t1 gets into the loop and reads the value of sum (10), then is stopped to let t2 begin running. t2, again, reads the value of sum (10) and then itself is stopped. Now t1 begins running again and it loops through 10 times setting the value of sum to 20. Now t2 starts up again and increments sum to 11, so you've actually decremented the value of sum.

Comment: Nice example of showing how the value could decrease.

Comment: It would be even worse if underlying hardware writes are not atomic or variable is not aligned. Due to limited range of values in question it is not likely, but imagine when one thread tries to write 0x0100, second 0x00FF and you will end with least significant from first thread and most significant from second.

Comment: It is not decremented. You just lost 10 increments.

Comment: @AhmadWabbi The increments still happened, so you didn't lose them. "Decrement" means to reduce in value, so moving from 20 to 10 is a decrement.

Comment: @Rick The increments happened but you lost their effect as the old value 10 took place. The value is relatively decremented, but globally saying, you lost some ++ operations. I am just against the word "Decrement"  because it is misleading. Can the final result be negative or less than 100? How can you explain the answer "no" (if it is "no") if there are decrements? Returning to an old value is not equivalent to "decrementing"

Answer (score 8):

It is undefined behavior so I am gong to say 42.  When you have more than one thread accessing a shared variable and at least on of them is a writer then you need synchronization.  If you do not have that synchronization then you have undefined behavior and we cannot tell you what will happen.

You could use a [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) or you could use a [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) to get synchronication and make the programs behavior defined.

Comment: I understand that I need mutex to lock the critical code. but what will be the values range?

Comment: @ItayAveksis Theroreticlly it could be anything but something between 100-200 is likely.  The problem is you could have torn reads in the increment section so you have no idea what the actual value is that you are incrementing.

Comment: but it's still 100 <= sum <= 200

Comment: @ItayAveksis It doesn't have to be.  likely it will be but who really can say.  It is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Since incrementation is not [atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), it will result in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: You linked to the french cppreference.  I wasn't even aware that there is a french cppreference

Comment: @ItayAveksis: firstly 'undefined behaviour' means you shouldn't make further assumptions, secondly we don't know how `Thread` is implemented, which doesn't help either.

Comment: @stefaanv : Ho you're right ! I missed that because the "Info" in head of page was in english. It's corrected.

Comment: @ItayAveksis : As explained in another answer, probably between 100 and 200, depending on the number of missed incrementations. But, I'm not totally sure, it can depend on specific implementation resulting in very strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a random value between 100 and 200. There is a race condition between the two threads without mutual exclusion. So, some ++ operations will be lost. This is why you will get 100 when all ++ operations of a thread are lost, and 200 when nothing is lost. Anything between may happen.

Comment: No. Undefined behavior means **undefined**. The result is not constrained to be between 100 and 200. (Note that the serial version of this program produces **202**).

Comment: It IS between 100 and 202 (not 200, as ther is i<=100 in the loop). "Undefined" means that you cannot know the value, but you can know the range. There are 202 increment operations in the code. At least, 100 of them will execute. At most, all of them are executed. Can you give me an execution scenario that yield the value 99, for example? @PeteBecker

Comment: The language definition says that the behavior of this program is **undefined**. That means the the language definition does not tell you what the program does. (if the result was required to be in a particular range the result would be **unspecified**) You can speculate all you like on what **might** happen, but unless your compiler documents how it handles that, your speculation means nothing. There's nothing preventing the compiler from observing that multiple threads are writing to the same location without synchronization, optimizing the increments away, and setting the value to 42.

Comment: @PeteBecker Your argument is so philosophic, and I will not continue in such a discussion as it is useless. Even though it is UNDEFINED in the language definition, in reality it is UNSPECIFIED. Compilers has nothing to do with it,  it is the nature of threads, and it cannot be 42.